# How to write two equations as part of one equation?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, bold

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x_{t}=f_{t}(x_{t-1},u_{t})}\\
\mathbf{y_{t}=g_{t}(x_{t},v_{t})}
\label{eq:state-space&obs-equ}
\end{align}
\end{equation}
```

I want that `y(t)` equation should come on next line but it comes on same line? how to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `\mathbf{x_{t}}&=\mathbf{f_{t}(x_{t-1},u_{t})}\\
\mathbf{y_{t}}&=\mathbf{g_{t}(x_{t},v_{t})}`

Comment: I already done this, but equations come on one line

Comment: You can not nest `equation` and `align`. Use only `align`.

Comment: Ok, I do not nest them, but when I use \begin{align} and \end{align} there comes some error

Comment: Please, note that you have to use `\mathbf` twice since the use of `&=`. Correct the braces `{}`.

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,preview]{standalone} % change it back to your document class
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\section*{side-by-side}
\begin{align}
x_{t} &= f_{t}(x_{t-1},u_{t}) & y_{t} &=g_{t}(x_{t},v_{t}) \label{eq:label1}
\end{align}
Please see equation~\ref{eq:label1} on page~\pageref{eq:label1}.

\section*{split with single number}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x_{t} &= f_{t}(x_{t-1},u_{t}) \\
y_{t} &=g_{t}(x_{t},v_{t}) 
\end{split}\label{eq:label2}
\end{equation}
Please see equation~\ref{eq:label2} on page~\pageref{eq:label2}.

\section*{aligned with single number}
\begin{equation}
\!
\begin{aligned}
x_{t} &= f_{t}(x_{t-1},u_{t}) \\
y_{t} &=g_{t}(x_{t},v_{t}) 
\end{aligned}\label{eq:label3}
\end{equation}
Please see equation~\ref{eq:label3} on page~\pageref{eq:label3}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\boldmath
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
x_t &= f_t(x_{t-1},u_t)\\
y_t &= g_t(x_t,v_t)
\end{aligned}\label{eq:state-space&obs-equ}
\end{align}

\unboldmath
\begin{align}
x_t &= f_t(x_{t-1},u_t)   &  y_t &= g_t(x_t,v_t)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

However, it is not a good idea to set the complete equations in bold.

[image]

Comment: still error, i am using winedit

Comment: and I want to be equation 1 and not equation 1 &2

Comment: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that you can't use `align` inside `equation` (and LaTeX will show you an error message that should tell you something is wrong with this). Just delete the `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` lines. This should work fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{align}
  \mathbf{x_{t}=f_{t}(x_{t-1},u_{t})}\\
  \mathbf{y_{t}=g_{t}(x_{t},v_{t})}
  \label{eq:state-space&obs-equ}
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

There are other things you may want to fix about this, e.g. putting in alignment points with `&`, but the minimum change required to fix the problem you're having now is getting rid of that `equation` environment.